# Can I have separate options for separate tasks in a Cakefile?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

The documentation I've seen for Cakefiles seems to be by example, where this serves as a typical example:

```
option '-v', '--verbose [TRUE|FALSE]', 'Turn verbosity on/off (off by default)'
task 'spec', 'run specs', (options) ->
  jasmine = require 'jasmine-node'
  # ...
```

But what happens when I want this:

```
option '-v', '--verbose [TRUE|FALSE]', 'Turn verbosity on/off (off by default)'
task 'spec', 'run specs', (options) ->
  jasmine = require 'jasmine-node'
  # ...

option '-d', '--directory [PATH]', 'specific directory to set up the widget in'
task 'createWidgets', 'create the widgets', (options) ->
  console.log options.verbose
```

Options are specific to the file, not the task, which means that (a) options bleed into all tasks in the file, and (b) when running `cake`, it's not clear to the user which options are associated with which tasks.

How do I associate options with particular tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to add task-specific options via any of the functions provided by `cake.coffee` -- if you look at the [source](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/cake.html) you'll see that options are handled globally. You *could* write that code yourself, extracting options on a per-task basis by writing code that reads off node's [`process.argv`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv). However, `cake.coffee` is really quite a bare-bones build tool, and I wouldn't recommend it for anything more than the simplest build systems. You might want to look at something like `rake` or `make` instead.